# Travis-CI config file customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

in my current travis-ci file i have this configurations.

NOTE: i want to customize this file as i don't have anything in `vendor/cache`. due to which am getting error on travis-ci build

```
0.44s$ bundle install --local
Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
The command "bundle install --local" failed and exited with 7 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

I just want to remove this error, but am totally unfamiliar with Travis-ci. also i dont want to put any gems in vendor/cache because it will make repo so much bigger in size. any help on this?

```
language: ruby
install: bundle install --local
cache:
  apt: true
  bundler: true
  directories:
  - vendor/cache

rvm:
- 2.2.2

addons:
  postgresql: 9.3
  code_climate:
      repo_token: 

before_script:
  - psql -U postgres -c "create extension postgis"
  - ./scripts/travis
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 1

script:
- RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec --pattern 'c*/*_spec.rb,h*/*_spec.rb'

env:
  matrix:
  - DATABASE_URL="postgres://localhost/evercam_tst"
  global:
  - secure: 
  - secure: 

branches:
  only: master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by removing that line

```
install: bundle install --local
```

and putting `cache: bundler`
 and deleting those lines its worked!

```
  apt: true
  bundler: true
  directories:
  - vendor/cache
```